# How to identify php.ini configuration causing trouble?

Tags: content-management-system, php

I've created a custom CMS, and it works perfectly on a local server using MAMP, even if content is stored in a remote database. However, when I run it on my client's host server, shit happens.

**The problem is that the CMS can't process texts which are longer than a few words.** By instance, if the text is "lorem ipsum" it'll work fine, but if the text is three paragraphs long, it will display an error submitting the post.

I'm assuming this is a php.ini issue, and **we have already changed php.ini memory_limit from 16M to 128M. However, the issue persists**.

**So my question is:** does anyone know of a good way of identifying what php.ini configurations cause trouble, other than changing them one by one?

Needless to say that if I run a phpinfo() on my local server and the host server a lot of the configurations are different...

Thank you for your time and help.

[EDIT]

This edit has been rewritten as an answer ;-)

Comment: I've already resolved my issue, so I will share what I've done, even though it's not exactly what I was asking for. Read [edit] on my question.

Comment: Good job on finding the solution your self :) It's recommended that you post your solution as an answer to this question and then select that answer as the correct one - this will make it obvious for anyone else searching your problem what the solution was!

Comment: Thanks for commenting, @bulk I will do that later. I'm a new user and can't answer my own questions yet

Comment: Ah fair enough, welcome to Stackoverflow! :)

Comment: It's a bit late now, but this question is probably a better fit at SO's sister site [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), as its topic is more about networks/servers than programming.

Comment: Thank you for telling @adamjansch . I didn't know this other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to check the most common php.ini configurations that CMS like Drupal or WordPress usually demand. One of them has to do with `magic_quotes_gpc`.

I found that my local server had this `On` and the host server had it `Off`, so I tried if there was an issue with that, and... there was.

I'm ashamed to say that, but the problem had to do with a bad practice on my side. I hadn't escaped properly the data coming from the posts form. After escaping all the `$_POST` with `mysql_real_escape_string()` everything worked fine.

**Lessons learned**

1. Always escape your form's data. No exceptions.
2. [Magic quotes have been deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php), and removed in PHP 5.4
3. Bad practices lead to errors at some point

I hope this will be useful to someone.